# SyntaxError: invalid syntax When Executing python modules as scripts

Tags: python-3.x

```
def good(n):
 if len(n)>5:
     print('good name')
 else:
     print('sorry better luck next time')

def nametest(n):
    if n.isalpha:
        print("yes sounds good")
    else:
        print("no its not a name !")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    nametest(sys.argv[1])
```

The above is my practice code saved as "namerating.py". I am trying to learn [Executing modules as script](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts). 
I got invalid syntax error when i try the below code in shell

```
python namerating.py 23
```

And below is the actual error

```
File "<pyshell>", line 1
    python namerating.py 23
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is being thrown because you did not correctly identify the good () function code block.

**Fixed Code:**

```
def good(n):
    if len(n)>5:
        print('good name')
    else:
        print('sorry better luck next time')

def nametest(n):
    if n.isalpha:
        print("yes sounds good")
    else:
        print("no its not a name !")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    nametest(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: if the function name is not supplied i wants to run namtest function as default. In that case what would be the solution?

Comment: That is another question and there is certainly an answer to it.